# Getting the sum of ages in overlapping age ranges in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

```
    target_value        title    people     start end   twitter_map
0   AGE_13_TO_17      13 to 17       1        13  17  AGE_13_TO_17
1   AGE_13_TO_24      13 to 24     NaN        13  24           NaN
2   AGE_13_TO_34      13 to 34     NaN        13  34           NaN
3   AGE_13_TO_49      13 to 49     NaN        13  49           NaN
4   AGE_13_TO_54      13 to 54     NaN        13  54           NaN
5   AGE_OVER_13     Age Over 13    NaN        13   -           NaN
6   AGE_18_TO_24      18 to 24       7        18  24  AGE_18_TO_24
7   AGE_18_TO_54      18 to 54     NaN        18  54           NaN
8   AGE_OVER_18     Age Over 18    NaN        18   -           NaN
9   AGE_21_TO_34      21 to 34     NaN        21  34           NaN
10  AGE_21_TO_49      21 to 49     NaN        21  49           NaN
11  AGE_21_TO_54      21 to 54     NaN        21  54           NaN
12  AGE_25_TO_34      25 to 34      34        25  34  AGE_25_TO_34
13  AGE_25_TO_49      25 to 49     NaN        25  49           NaN
14   AGE_OVER_25    Age Over 25    NaN        25   -           NaN
15  AGE_35_TO_44      35 to 44      15        35  44  AGE_35_TO_44
16   AGE_OVER_35    Age Over 35    NaN        35   -           NaN
17  AGE_45_TO_54      45 to 54       1        45  54  AGE_45_TO_54
18   AGE_OVER_50    Age Over 50    NaN        50   -           NaN
19  AGE_55_TO_64      55 to 64       3        55  64  AGE_55_TO_64
20   AGE_OVER_65          65+        6        65   -   AGE_OVER_65
21          None       All Ages    NaN  All Ages   -           NaN
```

So I have this dataframe as shown above with some values on age start and age end as show. But there are some overlapping age buckets. I need to fill the **people** column correctly based on the know values in **people** column

Expected Output for the first two rows

```
    target_value        title    people     start end   twitter_map
0   AGE_13_TO_17      13 to 17       1        13  17    AGE_13_TO_17
1   AGE_13_TO_24      13 to 24       8        13  24           NaN
```

Comment: The first three column have been joined with the last three columns

Comment: What's the expected output exactly?

Comment: I have given a sample on the first two rows ... i hope it  explains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will work on a simplified example:

```
people start end
     1    13  17
   NaN    13  24
   NaN    13  34
   NaN    13   -
     7    18  24
   NaN    18   -
    34    25  34
```

First replace `-` with infinity and convert all to float:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace({'-': np.inf}).astype(float)
```

Then select the rows where the number of 'people' is given, this will be the input:

```
df_input = df.dropna()
```

Now define the following function:

```
def func(row):
    return df_input.loc[
            (df_input['start'] >= row['start']) & (df_input['end'] <= row['end']),
            'people'
        ].sum()
```

For each row in the dataframe, it sums all the numbers in the input that satisfy the condition defining the age bracket (this is where infinity is useful).

Finally apply the function:

```
In [36]: df.apply(func, axis=1)
Out[36]: 
0     1.0
1     8.0
2    42.0
3    42.0
4     7.0
5    41.0
6    34.0
```

Comment: Thanks! For once I was faster ;)